# Why am I getting the "No binary found." error in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, configuration, cygwin

When trying to run this:

```
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

I get the

```
Launch failed. No binary found.
```

error. Why? I have the correct path set (`C:\cygwin64\bin`). Also, I have the `Cygwin` PE set too. Finally, I installed the `devel` package. Any help? 
Also getting the 3 errors of:

```
G++, gcc and make not found in PATH
```

Comment: What is the point of the program? It does *nothing*

Comment: That's my point; I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Joe It's not about what the program does, but why Eclipse fails to launch it.

Comment: You could use another IDE / compiler like Visual Studio or Borlands maybe

Comment: I could, but I'm stubborn. Thanks, though. I really like eclipse.

Comment: Build your program and for the first time click the arrow near "run", then select "run as" and there local c/c++ application

Comment: welp, I guess I didn't install it all...

Comment: Reinstalling the devel...

Comment: Installed devel, still getting the error. Also edited the post to errors that I didn't see. :P

Comment: It seems like you don't have a compiler, or it does not know where it is located: it cannot find the GCC g++ compiler and the makefile it would create

Comment: Isn't the compiler supposed to download with the devel package of cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) instead, it works perfectly with eclipse: just make sure to set the install directory to `C:\MinGW` (the directory name is case-sensitive).

Then you have to set a compiler for your projects: Go to Window -> Prefrences then

[image]

Then create a new project and set the compiler for it:

[image]

Before run your program build your project: Project -> Build Project

Comment: No just select the compiler you installed instead

Comment: Try to install MinGW it works perfectly with eclipse

Comment: Did you install MinGW or just with your compiler?